# Java: Cannot resolve method 'setVisible(boolean)'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want my program to open a second form (that was created) when the SkipBtn is clicked, but IntelliJ throws this error:

> Error:(24, 19) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   method
>   setVisible(boolean)   location: variable pw of type
>   com.timeforbreak.PasswordWindow

My code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class BreakWindow {
    private JButton skipBtn;
    private JPanel breakWindow;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BreakWindow");
        frame.setContentPane(new BreakWindow().breakWindow);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public BreakWindow() {
        skipBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                PasswordWindow pw = new PasswordWindow();
                pw.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

=================================

```
package com.timeforbreak;

import javax.swing.*;

public class PasswordWindow extends BreakWindow {
    private JTextField password;
    private JPanel passwordWindow;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PasswordWindow");
        frame.setContentPane(new PasswordWindow().passwordWindow);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your frame is a local variable it can't access outside the method try making JFrame frame global variable.

declare `JFrame frame;` outside the main method and initialize it inside the main method

Comment: How can I do this? I am new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating PasswordWindow:

```
PasswordWindow pw = new PasswordWindow();
```

which extends `BreakWindow`:

```
public class PasswordWindow extends BreakWindow
```

but `BreakWindow` is your first class with `main` and there is no such method `setVisible(boolean)`.

Your `BreakWindow` should extend `JFrame` and you can do so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new BreakWindow("BreakWindow"); // was JFrame
```

Don't remember insert corresponding constuctor to your `BreakWindow` class.